# JavaScript object properties are "sometimes" undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, tinymce

I am very confused.

I created the following script which is located at http://tapmeister.com/test/dom.html.  For some unknown reason, tinymce.editors.ta1 and tinymce.editors[0] show up as undefined, and attempting to use a method under them results in an error.  But when I inspect tinymce or tinymce.editors using FireBug, I see them in the DOM.

So, I create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JWyWM/ to show the people on stackoverflow.  But when I test it out, tinymce.editors.ta1 and tinymce.editors[0] are no longer undefined, and the methods work without error.

What is going on???  Maybe something to do with public/protected/private properties? How do I access methods such as `tinymce.editors.ta1.hide()`?  Thank you!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            tinymce.init({selector: "textarea#ta1"});
            tinymce.init({selector: "textarea#ta2"});
            console.log(tinymce);
            console.log(tinymce.editors);
            console.log(tinymce.editors.ta1);
            console.log(tinymce.editors[0]);
            //tinymce.editors.ta1.hide();
            //alert('pause');
            //tinymce.editors.ta1.show();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
            <textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE doesn't do all of the setup work immediately when you call `init`. It provides a callback, `setup`, to tell you when the work is done.

So if you provide a `setup` callback, you can interact with the editor instance then.

Here's an example (I've also moved your scripts to the end, [which is best practice regardless](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)):

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ucehud/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ucehud/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
            <textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
        </form>
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "#ta1, #ta2",
                setup:    function(e) {
                    console.log("Editor " + e.id + " is ready");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Now, if you want to actually access the editor instance, bizarrely TinyMCE doesn't add it to `tinymce.editors` until *after* calling the `setup` function. But if you throw in a brief yield, you're all set. Here's the above with a changed `setup` function:

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ucehud/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ucehud/3/edit)

```
setup:    function(e) {
  // Bizarrely, TinyMCE calls `setup` *before* adding
  // the relevant editor to `tinymce.editors`,
  // so we have to yield briefly
  console.log("Editor " + e.id + " is ready");
  if (e.id === "ta2") {
    console.log("It's ta2, I'll hide it in a moment.");
    setTimeout(function() {
      tinymce.editors[e.id].hide();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

So why did it work on jsFiddle? Well, jsFiddle has a <s>truly brain dead</s> *surprising* default setting, which is to put all of your script in a `window#load` callback function. `window#load` happens **very** late in the load process, after all external resources have been loaded. (You can see that in the jsFiddle UI, it's the second drop-down list on the left.) So apparently TinyMCE was completely ready at that point, where it isn't earlier in the cycle.

Side note: 99.9% of the time, there is absolutely no point in supplying a tag name with an `id` selector, e.g. `textarea#ta1`. `id` values are unique, so you don't have to qualify them unless you explicitly want to avoid matching an element that may sometimes have one tag name, or other times have another, which is a pretty unusual use case.

Comment: I revised the code as you suggested, and the results are no different.  Please take a look at http://tapmeister.com/test/dom.html.  Thank you

Comment: @user1032531: No, don't ask people to visit random sites to help you. We don't take these things off-site. (Why: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question) I have, however, figured out what the problem is. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry TJ, I won't do it again.  I will take steps to learn to use http://jsbin.com.  Also, I agree about the uselessness of `textarea#ta1`.  It was actually in the TinyMCE example.  Thank you for showing me that I can use `selector: "#ta1, #ta2"`.  Lastly, I don't think the revised solution works.  I need to be able to access the editor methods such as `tinymce.editors.ta1.hide()`.  I will create a sample on http://jsbin.com and post it.  Thank you for your help

Comment: @user1032531: You can access them, let me update to show you how. One sec.

Comment: Thanks again TJ.  Yes, it is bizarre how you have to wait.  Also, why do the properties show up under FireBug/Chrome console only if you start with a parent property (i.e. tinymce and tinymce.editors) instead of the child property (i.e. tinymce.editors.ta1)?  Sounds like I need to put everything in setup callback.  How would I initiate something in there from some external event such as clicking a button?

Comment: @user1032531: When you dump out an object via Chrome's `console.log`, it dumps out a *live copy*. So if the state of the object changes later, it gets reflected in that display. Confuses the heck out of people. When you're dealing with a button click or whatever, you should be able to use `tinymce.editors.ta1` and `.ta2` just fine (provided the setup is complete). You could have the button disabled until the setup fires.

Comment: Determinately confused the heck out of me!  Yes, I figured out how to add some click event inside the setup callback, and it works great.  I appreciated your help on this confusing topic!

Answer (score -1):

There's a large chance that your script is running before tinyMCE has actually loaded. It might be the case that it loads faster from your test site so that is why it works.

Use  as a quick check.