# Mimicing event inside callback function from external of callback

Tags: javascript, oop, events, tinymce, dom-events

Upon a given event, I wish to trigger a given action.  In particular, I would like to hide an editor by performing `tinymce.editors['myID'].hide();`.  Turns out this method is only available within the `setback()` callback function.  Why this is so, I have no idea, but people much smarter than me say it is true as discussed in 
[JavaScript object properties are "sometimes" undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590419/javascript-object-properties-are-sometimes-undefined).

One way to do this is to add the following script in the `setup()` callback function.

```
$('#hide1').click(function(){tinymce.editors['myID'].hide();});
```

While this will work, my realworld example is a little more complicated.  The event will start with a click, then do an ajax call, and based on the returned JSON, will do some other work and may or may not hide the editor.  I really don't want to duplicate all the logic/ajax both inside `setup()` and in other parts of the application.  Instead, I am hoping I can put the logic/ajax outside of `setup()` and use it to somehow trigger `tinymce.editors['myID'].hide();` which is located in `setup()`.

I hope this makes sense to you, because it is pretty confusion to me.

Live Example: http://jsbin.com/ogirab/3/ | With Code: http://jsbin.com/ogirab/3/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea id="myID"></textarea>
        </form>
        <button id="hide1">Hide using event linked directly in setup</button>
        <button id="hide2">Hide by mimicing an event</button>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "#myID",
                    setup:    function(e) {
                        $('#hide1').click(function(){tinymce.editors['myID'].hide();});
                    }
                });
                $('#hide2').click(function(){alert('trigger event which will cause function in tinymce::setup() to trigger.');});
            });
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `$(function(){});` at the end of the `<body>`. That's used to bind an event for when the DOM is ready, which is basically the same as at the end of the `<body>`

Comment: @Ian  I thought the same thing, but it seemed to caused a problem with the `click()` method inside of `setup()`.

Comment: by sticking `tinymce.editors['myID'].hide();` inside the `#hide2` click function, it works for me.

Comment: @XGundam05.  That is weird.  I think you are correct.  When I was first testing, I put `tinymce.editors['myID'].hide();` directly in the main script (i.e. not in the click event), and it showed `tinymce.editors['myID'];` as being undefined.